# Add to add token filter to SearchKick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a fairly simple use case, but so far it has been painful trying to find proper syntax.

I have written a few token filters:

```
  searchkick **{
    settings: {
      analysis: {
        filter: {
          replace_mm: {
            type: 'pattern_replace',
            pattern: '(\\d)mm',
            replacement: '$1 mm ',
          },
          replace_x_1: {
            type: 'pattern_replace',
            pattern: '(\\d) ?(×|x)',
            replacement: '$1 x ',
          },
          replace_x_2: {
            type: 'pattern_replace',
            pattern: '(×|x) ?(\\d)',
            replacement: ' x $2',
          },
          searchkick_edge_ngram: {
            type: 'edge_ngram',
            min_gram: 1,
            max_gram: 50
          },
        },
        analyzer: {
          custom_index: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: [
              'replace_mm',
              'replace_x_1',
              'replace_x_2',
              'lowercase',
              'asciifolding',
              'searchkick_edge_ngram',
            ],
          },
          # https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/ee62747af38b264574995341b70bdad432f65e0f/lib/searchkick/index_options.rb#L95
          searchkick_word_start_index: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: [
              'lowercase',
              'asciifolding',
              'searchkick_edge_ngram',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
    mappings: {
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: 'text',
          analyzer: 'custom_index',
        },
        alternate_names: {
          type: 'text',
          analyzer: 'custom_index',
        },
        description: {
          type: 'text',
          analyzer: 'searchkick_word_start_index',
        },
      },
    },
    highlight: [
      :name,
    ],
    search_synonyms: [
      # ...
    ]
  }
```

How do I actually make the indexing + search uitilize these filters. I want everything to remain the default, id like to just override the filters, to add a few more, as everything else works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is probably to leverage the [`merge_mappings` parameter](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-mapping) and providing custom mappings/settings.

```
searchkick merge_mappings: true, mappings: {...}, settings: {...}
```

If you want to add additional token filters, you also need to create additional analyzers in order to use them, as you cannot use a token filter directly, [they are part of the analysis chain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html). So you started the right way, by adding your token filters into custom settings, but now you also need to add new analyzers to your custom settings, or override existing ones.

The second part of the job, is to also provide custom mappings in order to leverage the new analyzer(s), unless you have overridden the existing analyzer of your field.

Looking at how the [default settings are defined](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/ee62747af38b264574995341b70bdad432f65e0f/lib/searchkick/index_options.rb#L30), your settings structure needs to be like this in order to be correctly merged:

```
{
  settings: {
    analysis: {
      filter: {
        replace_mm: {
          type: 'pattern_replace',
          pattern: '(\\d)mm',
          replacement: '$1 mm ',
        },
        replace_x_1: {
          type: 'pattern_replace',
          pattern: '(\\d) ?(×|x)',
          replacement: '$1 x ',
        },
        replace_x_2: {
          type: 'pattern_replace',
          pattern: '(×|x) ?(\\d)',
          replacement: ' x $2',
        },
      },
      analyzer: {
        my_new_analyzer: { ... },
        existing_analyzer: { ... },
      }
    },
  },
  mappings: {
    properties: {
      your_field: {
        type: text,
        analyzer: my_new_analyzer
      }
    }
  }
```

`my_new_analyzer` would be a new analyzer that you can use for one of your fields in a custom mapping (if provided), whereas `existing_analyzer` would be an override of an existing one that takes into account your new token filters.

Which analyzer you override depends on the [type of your field](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/ee62747af38b264574995341b70bdad432f65e0f/lib/searchkick/index_options.rb#L390) as there's one different analyzer per type named `searchkick_#{type}_index` (full list [available here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/ee62747af38b264574995341b70bdad432f65e0f/lib/searchkick/index_options.rb#L75-L109)).

I hope this sets you on the right track.

**edit**

I'm also trying to find out how to use this at search time

```
    rows = Something.search({
      body: {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: params[:query],
            type: '',
            fields: [
              '',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

Comment: Here is the error I get when I try that way: `Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"unknown parameter [ignore_above] on mapper [name] of type [text]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: unknown parameter [ignore_above] on mapper [name] of type [text]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"unknown parameter [ignore_above] on mapper [name] of type [text]"}},"status":400}`

Comment: Ok, I think it's mainly [because of this](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/ee62747af38b264574995341b70bdad432f65e0f/lib/searchkick/index_options.rb#L346-L347) where all fields are mapped as `keyword` [if flagged `filterable`](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#filterable-fields) and `text` if [flagged as `searchable`](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#searchable-fields). How are your `name` and `alternate_names` fields flagged?

Comment: Hey I changed my question to include what I have. I'm using `word_start: [:combined, :name, :description]` because its going to be used for autocomplete dropdown. i havent 'flagged' anything specifically though.

Comment: so I think ive solved it one way. I basically took out merge mappings and then just custom added all the things that are referenced for word_start: `searchkick_edge_ngram`, `searchkick_word_start_index`. Heres my question though now... is "searchkick_word_start_index" what is actually used for "word_start"? or something else. I notice theres a few things like word_search, etc. i picked the one that seemed most likely, but i dont know if thats actually the deefault for word_start

Comment: ok `word_start` means you're using the [`searchkick_word_start_index` analyzer](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/ee62747af38b264574995341b70bdad432f65e0f/lib/searchkick/index_options.rb#L95-L99) for the listed fields. Can you try to override that analyzer in the settings but without adding custom mappings, i.e. you stick with the default mappings, but you override what the analyzer does with your `cartridge_synonyms` filter? PS: we wrote the same thing at the same time, great minds... :-)

Comment: `searchkick_word_start_index` is the analyzer used at indexing time. At query time, it's probably the `searchkick_search` analyzer kicking in

Comment: hey -- Ive actually kept `searchkick_word_start_index` because I want to use that for the "description" field (it will involve regular sentences). I want to use `custom_analyzer` on `name` (text) and `alternate_names` (array of text). Ive changed my original question to show this... now another tricky part, now that im using these custom mappings, how do I actually utilize them at search time. if I look at the query generated by searchkick its massive... im hoping i dont need to paste that entire thing in. I have modified my question to also include what i have so far of search query object.

Comment: anyone else reading this, it was because i didnt destructure the keyword arguments `**{ body: {} }`